# Extract Function name from Notepad++ for FunctionList

Tags: regex, windows, function, notepad++

I am trying to set up a **Function List** for a new language in **Notepad++**. To do so, it requires me to add a parser in `functionlist.xml`. I added the parser, and it works, but it also adds the actual word `function` in the function list. How can I remove word function from it? I have looked into the Regular Expression's lookbehind feature. But I could not make it work.

**Here is the parser.**

```
<parser displayName="mylang" id="mylang_syntax">
  <function mainExpr="^\s*(function|Function|FUNCTION)[\t ]+[\w]+">
    <functionName>
      <NameExpr expr="/(?<=^function /)[\w]+" />
      <NameExpr expr="/(?<=^Function /)[\w]+" />
      <nameexpr expr="/(?<=^FUNCTION /)[\w]+" />
    </functionName>
  </function>
</parser>
```

**Here is an example text to try on**.

```
FUNCTION uniqn, input_array
  IF(!DEBUG) THEN PRINT, 'uniqn_no_sort'
  counter = 0L
  length = n_elements(input_array(*, 0))
  duplicate_array = STRARR(length)
END

function get_algorithm_type, type
  IF(!DEBUG) THEN PRINT, 'get_algorithm_type'
  print, type
END
```

This is how it looks in the functionlist sidebar. I would like to remove the word 'function'. **Please note** that it needs to work in Notepad++. (I cannot use any other Text editors). Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

Here are additional help.

- https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/function-list.html
- https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/14328/user-defined-functionlist-no-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Regex below:

```
(?i)(?<=^function)\s+\K\w+
```

**[Click for Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pORY2y/1)**

**Regex Explanation:**

- `(?i)` - modifier to make the search case-insensitive
- `(?<=^function)` - positive lookbehind to find the position immediately preceded by the sub-string `function` at the start of the line
- `\s+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a white-space character
- `\K` - forget everything matched so far
- `\w+` - matches 1+ occurrences of all the characters which fall within the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Add the following `parser` tag to the file `functionList.xml`

```
<parser id="mylang" displayName="mylang_syntax">
    <function mainExpr="(?i)(?<=^function)\s+\K\w+" />
</parser>
```

**OUTPUT**

As you can see below, extra spaces between the `function` and the `functionName` have also been ignored
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Gurman. It works great. `\K` was awesome. I did not know such feature existed. I have one more small request. Is it possible to add another type of function, which actually start with `pro`.

  `pro another_routine, type
    IF(!DEBUG) THEN PRINT, 'get_algorithm_type'
    print, type
  END`

Comment: @Cricrazy For that case, you can use this regex [`(?i)(?:(?<=^function)|(?<=^pro))\s+\K\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/pORY2y/2)

Comment: @Cricrazy Also, If the answer helped you, please consider upvoting it or accepting the answer

Comment: works perfectly. Accepted as the answer most gladly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
<parser displayName="mylang" id="mylang_syntax">
  <function mainExpr="(?<=function|Function|FUNCTION)[\t ]+[\w]+"/>
</parser>
```

and you get

[image]